# jQuery issue for deleting input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an input field when clicking on `add`, and it should be removed when clicking on `delete` click.

Here is *JS Bin* link:
[JS issue with deletion](https://jsbin.com/zekivab/edit?html,js,output)

```js
var newTextBoxDiv;
var rowCount = 0;
var counter = 1;
var delCounter = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('focus', '.txtFocus', function() {
        $(this).next('.clearContent').hide()
    });
    $(document).on('focusout', '.txtFocus', function() {
        $('.clearContent').show()
    })
});
    
function addTags(obj) {
    var newTextBoxDiv = '<div class="col-md-4 TextBoxMainDiv"><div style=""><div class="input-group" id="" style="width: 40%;margin: 0;padding: 0;padding: 2px;float:left;width:80%;"><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value=""  class="txtFocus" required  placeholder="Add Tag"   autocomplete="false" style="width: 100%" ><span class="clearContent"><a href="#" onClick="deleteTag(this);"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></span> </div><div style="width: 15%;display: inline-block;text-align:right;"><span id="addMore" onClick="addTags(this);"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a></span></div></div></div>';
    $(obj).hide();
    $("#tagElement").append(newTextBoxDiv);
    $('.txtFocus').focus();
    counter++;
    if (counter == 1) {
        $(obj).show()
    }
}
    
function deleteTag(obj) {
    $(obj).closest('.TextBoxMainDiv').last().find('#addMore').show();
    $(obj).closest('.TextBoxMainDiv').last().find('#addMore').css('display', 'block');
    $(obj).closest('.TextBoxMainDiv').remove();
    counter--;
    if (counter == 1) {
        $('#addMore').show()
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="tagElement">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 TextBoxMainDiv">
            <div style="">
                <div class="input-group" id="" style="width: 40%;margin: 0;padding: 0;padding: 2px;float:left;width:80%;">
                    <input type="text" class="txtFocus" required placeholder="Add Tag" id="textBox" autocomplete="false" autofocus="autofocus" style="width: 100%">
                    <span class="clearContent">
                        <a href="#" onClick="deleteTag(this);">Add</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 15%;display: inline-block;text-align:right;">
                    <span id="addMore" onClick="addTags(this);">
                        <a href="#">cancel</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

I manage to add the input fields properly, but have issues deleting them. They seem to be deleted randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the add and delete button are mixed up, but I couldn't spend time on analysing the code because it's too much code for something that does very little. The following demo:

- has a single button that adds a row of form controls:

  - a checkbox
  - a text input
  - a button that deletes it's own row as well as itself.

---

### Demo

```js
var index = 0;
var template = `
  <figure class='frame'><input class='status' type='checkbox'><label class='tag'></label><input class='text' type='text' placeholder='Enter New Task'><button class='del' type='button'>&#10134;</button></figure>`;

$('.set').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('add')) {
    index++;
    $('.set').prepend(template);
    $('.status:eq(0)').attr('id', 'chx' + index);
    $('.tag:eq(0)').attr('for', 'chx' + index);
  } else {
    $(this).prevUntil('.del, .add').add(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.set {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 0 1px 2px;
  min-height: 28px;
  border-radius:7px;
}

.frame {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width:90vw;
  }
  
.add {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 3px;
  display:block;
}

.status {
  display: none
}

.tag {
  display: inline-table;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.tag::before {
  content: '\2610';
}

.status:checked+.tag::before {
  content: '\2611'
}

.text {
  display:inline-table;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 2px 5px 0
}
```

```html
<form id='ui'>

  <fieldset class='set'>
  <figure class='frame'>
    <input id='chx0' class='status' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='chx0' class='tag'></label>
    <input class='text' type='text' placeholder='Enter New Task' style='margin:2.5px 2px 0 0' autofocus>
    <button class='del' type='button'>&#10134;</button>
    </figure>
    <button class='add' type='button'>&#10133;</button>
  </fieldset>

</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, this is not the requirement, Add button should always with Input Text field and on click, it should add another Text Box and then "Add" button moves to that newly added field.

And on "Delete" the textbox must be deleted which is correct as per your demo, but again "add" button moves to that field. In other words, you can say that, there should be 2 buttons "add" & "delete" with Input Text Box in your demo. BUT Delete button always stay with Input Text Box whereas "Add" moves to NEW ADDED TEXT BOX.

Comment: @BalkarKalsi demo has been updated, `.add` is now abpos. So now `.add` never moves but will always be on the top row where the newest textbox is always positioned.

Comment: whereas "Add" moves to NEW ADDED TEXT BOX.---- THIS IS CLEARLY MENTIONED AS LAST LINE.......It should not Stick to 1 position always, but moves with Delete button.

see: INPUT FIELD HAS DELETE AND ADD, BUT WHEN WE ADD MORE INPUT FIELDS, THE ADD BUTTON MOVES TO LAST INPUT FIELD AND WHEN WE DELETE, IT SHOULD ALWAYS REMAIN WITH LAST INPUT FIELD

Comment: **I DOESN'T NEED TO MOVE, IT IS ALWAYS AT THE NEWEST TEXTBOX AT THE TOP** Moving a button while the user is using it is very bad UX, your design logic is very flawed, **AND IT'S VERY RUDE TO USE ALL CAPS**

Comment: Also, your list is appending therefore the newest textbox gets pushed down to the bottom (bad UX). Mine prepends which stacks the newest textbox to the top (good UX).

Comment: Please don't do any more efforts / comments, that is not my requirement. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: You could easily switch the flow and have it behave the way you want. My jQuery is only 10 lines and it works flawlessly. Or just follow Ray Cham's detailed advice. It looks as if you just want code exactly the way you want it without any work or thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code's logic is working, however, the icon for addition and deletion of inputs is not being rendered.

You can replace your `newTextBoxDiv` with this:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = `
    <div class="col-md-4 TextBoxMainDiv">
        <div style="">
            <div class="input-group" id="" style="width: 40%;margin: 0;padding: 0;padding: 2px; float:left; width:80%;">
                <input type="text" name="textbox${counter}" id="textbox${counter}" value="" class="txtFocus" required placeholder="Add Tag" autocomplete="false" style="width: 100%" >
                <span class="clearContent">
                    <a href="#" onClick="deleteTag(this);">Delete<i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        <div style="width: 15%;display: inline-block;text-align:right;">
            <span id="addMore" onClick="addTags(this);">
                <a href="#">Add</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>`;
```

Notice that I added the word "Add" and "Delete" between the  tags, so that you have something to click on

Also, I think you need to swap the word "Add" and "Cancel" in the initial HTML to convey a clearer message, as they are now doing the opposite thing.

Another fix that's needed is to replace the `id="addMore"` with `class="addMore"`

`<span class="addMore" onClick="addTags(this);">`

Since id is meant to be unique. In your code, however, when you append new element, you added new elements with duplicate id, making jquery's selector not selecting the element you want.

After replacing id with class, you also need to change the deleteTag function to select the last "addMore" span and show it.

```
function deleteTag(obj) {
    $(obj).closest('.TextBoxMainDiv').last().find('.addMore').show();
    $(obj).closest('.TextBoxMainDiv').last().find('.addMore').css('display', 'block');
    $(obj).closest('.TextBoxMainDiv').remove();
    counter--;
    $('.addMore').last().show();
}
```

For the layout, you need to do it with css, removing float and setting the div tag with appropriate width and display: inline-block. I suggest you use a separate css file to style the elements instead of doing it inline.

```js
function deleteTodo() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}

function addTodo() {
    var inputTemplate =
        '<div class="todo-input-wrapper">' +
            '<input class="todo-input" type="text" placeholder="Add Tag" />' +
            '<button class="delete-button">Delete</button>' +
        '</div>';
    $('.todo-wrapper').append(inputTemplate);
    $('.delete-button').last().on('click', deleteTodo);
    $('.todo-input').last().focus();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.delete-button').on('click', deleteTodo);
    $('.add-button').on('click', addTodo);
});
```

```css
.todo-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: max-content;
    font-size: 0;
}

.todo-input-wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-wrapper">
    <div class="todo-input-wrapper">
        <input class="todo-input" type="text" placeholder="Add Tag" />
        <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="add-button">Add</button>
```

Comment: Well many thanks for your reply, I would like to add that - whenever user clicks  ANY "x  / DELETE" icon IN ANY Text Input Field, it should be removed, BUT "+ / ADD"  icon SHOULD NOT REPEATED /  DISPLAY MORE THAN ONE AND STICK TO LAST TEXT FIELD ALWAYS

Comment: So, you want to show at most one ADD button, and that button should appears next to the last input?

Comment: yes, whatever I delete any input field, the "Add" icon must stick to it and not repeat with any other Input field.

Comment: @BalkarKalsi I think what zer00one said is very reasonable and maybe you should consider it. But in case for some reason, you want to do it like what you suggested, I added a code snippet for it. I hope it helps.